# Woocommerce do not show product description on catalog page but still show in single product pages

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce, product

The catalog page gets too cluttered with the product's description and short description ranging in different lengths. This off sets each product differently and I would prefer each product to take up more a less the same space in the catalog grid. Thus I would like to remove the product's description from the catalog page and only show it in the single product page when a user selects a product. If possible I would also prefer the search function to not include text from the product short description. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this still the case with a default theme? Because `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt()` which displays the excerpt is not called by WooCommerce's `content-product.php` template, which is the template displayed by default in the archive loops. Meaning, that it could be added by your theme.

Comment: Hi, yes to my knowledge it is the default, however I am running various plugins and a child theme template (Templatemela). I have looked for hours through all the options and I can say quite confidently that there is no allowance for the description to be removed from the catalog page. I have however found a work-around, I got the idea from a similar question to remove the short details from the single product page. Edit the css file: wp-content -> themes -> myTheme -> css -> woocommerce.css. Add the following code: .product-block-inner > div[itemprop="description"] {
    display: none;
}

Comment: No, I mean a default theme like Twenty Sixteen, because as far as I can tell from WooCommerce the excerpt should not be there. Here's a [Twenty Sixteen screenshot](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/1610/GiDr6n.jpg) I'd suggest looking at your theme's `content-product.php` template and/or searching your theme to see if `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` is being added to a hook somewhere.

Comment: Ah no, I am using a them called Digita. Thank you for your assistance, I can't find woocommerce_template_single_excerpt in my content-product.php but the fix I found will do for now.

Comment: Then presumably `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` is being added to a hook. But CSS will work in a pinch.

Answer (score 2):

```
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_post_excerpt ) { 
if(is_shop() || is_product_category() ) {
    return false;
} else {
    return $post_post_excerpt; 
}    
};  
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'filter_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1 );
```